# Custom tags are not saved

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, new-nav

Some ~ 5 hours ago, I removed some tags from "custom-tags".  Now, (on another machine with same account), the deleted tags are back. For one, I deleted [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda).

Maybe I do not get it what custom-tags are for ...

... and again. My saves that I did after writing this questions are gone.

Comment: Just checking: You did click *Apply* after you clicked the red delete icon?

Comment: (just checked what you meant by Apply - the big blue rectangle): Yes, I did.

Comment: sorry to bother cant find any reference to custom-tag what are them exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

Custom tags are indeed not saved against your account; editing the custom tags *changes the url* - and you are more than welcome to bookmark that etc; but basically this is just a bespoke filter (just like navigating to a different composite set of tags) - as opposed to "all tags",  "recommended", "favorite", etc.

Comment: OK, that is extremely unintuitive behavior to me. And, editing the url directly is much simpler than editing the tags!

Comment: @false that depends a bit on whether the tags you are choosing need to be %-encoded, and whether you know the exact name of the tag (as opposed  to using the picker), etc...

Comment: It is fine when adding a new tag, indeed. But to remove tags, I have first to laboriously hit the left-arrow key before I can remove one. Just as complex as editing the url, but entirely unexpected.

Comment: @false ctrl+left works in most browsers to jump by whole words (tags), or you can use the mouse: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tpfFH.png